# Jquery plugins - iphone scroll acceleration

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Are there any jquery plugins that can simulate the acceleration on an iphone when scrolling - doesnt have to be exactly like it but anything remotely similar.  I cant seem to find anything.

Along the same lines, are there any really, good examples of smooth javascript scrolling out there?  Most javascript scrolling seems jittery in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I've used [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) in a previous project, it runs really smooth (particularly on the 3GS/4). There are several examples and and a demo on the site.

Answer (score 0):

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

try easing plugin. there are loads of different animation options.